# When do posters know their questions are being voted to close?

Tags: support

A poster asks a question that qualifies for closing. For example, take a question dealing with an unsupported distribution.

I vote to close as off-topic and mine is the first vote.

Does the questioner immediately know that a vote to close has been cast with the reason

> "This is not about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions
>   can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User, those
>   about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming
>   questions on Stack Overflow."

that ultimately appears?

My question is **not** about the poster discovering my "identity". It's about wanting to know if I'm **adding any value** by adding a comment of my own such as:

> This site offers support only for [official flavors of
>   Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours). *XXX* is off-topic
>   here but questions about it are welcome at
>   https://unix.stackexchange.com.

I feel that a comment such I've posted above would be superfluous if the questioner can immediately see the official comment.

Comment: Lets find. I've voted to close [your question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1139732/816190). Do you see anything?

Comment: @Kulfy haha, nice!

Comment: @dessert Doubt would be cleared if tried personally :)

Comment: @Kulfy was it this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139732/is-there-a-file-manager-that-can-serially-number-files-and-subfolders-in-the-cur? All I see is close(1) with no explanation. So our adding comments would be useful as Fabby points out.

Comment: Indeed. Retracted my close vote :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will not see anything until 5 people agree (or a gold badge user / mod uses their gold hammer / [Orbital cannon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqEH8.jpg)).

So **yes, you're adding value**, but I'd use:

> This site offers support only for [official flavours of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours). XXX is off-topic here but welcomed at [unix.se], a sister site of [ubuntu.se].

Which should expand to:

> This site offers support only for [official flavours of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours). XXX is off-topic here but  welcomed at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), a sister site of [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)

Comment: Are you sure they will not see anything? When voting to close as duplicate the OP actually sees a message before the voting has passed. The message will something similar to "This question may have an answer here [link to another question]" and only they will see it. Has this been changed or is it different for off-topic votes? But I do agree a message will add value whether they see a message or not.

Comment: I'd suggest adding [ElementaryOS - Stack Exchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/) in comments for questions specifically for Elementary OS. Lets help the site to grow **:-)**

Comment: @Dan Duplicate is different...

Comment: I'll now add to and modify my Texpander list of boilerplate comments!

Comment: When users have 250 reputations, they have a privilege to [view close votes](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) on their own posts. However, it's correct that they're not notified at all (except from the comment when voting to close as a dupe)